# Is there any drawback on opening a new table for every row of another table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Currently I am working on an old content management system. The system let the user create pages for their member site and will log page view on member. Normally I would expect the database to look something like this:

```
page_table
    page_id
    (Some other field about page)

member_table
    member_id
    (Some other field about member)

page_view_log_table
    page_id
    member_id
    view_time
```

However, the database actually look like this:

```
page_table
    page_id
    (Some other field about page)

member_table
    member_id
    (Some other field about member)

page_(page_id)_view_log_table
    member_id
    view_time

page_(page_id)_view_log_table
    member_id
    view_time    

page_(page_id)_view_log_table
    member_id
    view_time

.......
```

i.e. The previous developer choose to open a new table for view log for every page. He claims that is because there are too many view and this improve the performance when generating the view log report with respect to page. Usually the site won't contain too many pages (below 50) so it won't create too many tables.

He is correct. I have done an experiment by copying the database and try to put all data into one table. (and it takes an hour to copy the database, so you can image the number of page view) The performance increase a lot especially on pages with less page view. I just don't feel comfortable as it seems it is not a normal practice. Is there any drawbacks on this practice? Or is there better way to handle the problem?

---

**P.S.** I am just using the amount of time to copy to say the database is big. I do the experiment by actually using the system as normal user to generate page view report. Sorry for unclear question.

Comment: It is rarely advisable to have two tables with the same schema.

Comment: Seems like breaking the page_view_log_table up into separate tables was an attempt to solve some sort of problem. Avoiding table lock contention for DML executed against MyISAM tables? Long running queries because suitable indexes are not available or the queries are not written to respect available indexes? We're not really sure what problem was being addressed, but we strongly suspect that breaking the table up into separate tables was probably not the best solution to whatever problem that problem was. (And the amount of time to copy the tables isn't the right measure of performance.)

Comment: Any drawback? Hm, well apart from it being entirely antithetical to the whole concept of an RDBMS, nigh impossible to maintain, slow, and terribly inefficient, no; not really.

Answer (score 2):

> He is correct. I have done an experiment by copying the database and
>   try to put all data into one table. (and it takes an hour to copy the
>   database, so you can image the number of page view)

unfortunately you have used a completely irrelevant yardstick to make the judgment. Copying data from one (or many) tables to another is something that happens very very rarely such as when you are doing maintenance work like this. It shouldn't be used to measure how well the system will perform under ordinary circumstances.

Your design is essentially correct and the previous developer must have smoked something really strong when he came up with that design.

```
page_table
    page_id
    (Some other field about page)

member_table
    member_id
    (Some other field about member)

page_view_log_table
    page_id
    member_id
    view_time
```

You just need to use the right indexes to make sure that the retrievals are fast. Don't add too many indexes, then the inserts will be slow. It seems that a combined index on `(page_id,member_id)` will give you the right balance.

Comment: ... assuming the `page_xxx_view_log_table` are InnoDB and not MyISAM. (We would expect them to be InnoDB, but who are we to assume?) The previous developer may have been concerned that   MyISAM tables would be subject to contention due to table locks taken by DML (for example, INSERT) statements. Spreading the inserts to different tables may have mitigated that contention.

Comment: Either that, or the queries were not written with regard for proper indexes, and/or suitable indexes are not available, so SELECT statements may be doing full scans of the tables. Breaking the table up into separate tables is the poor man's way of partitioning the table.

Comment: You are right that I have forgot to set index when I am doing my experiment. Maybe I will repeat the experiment when I have time.

Comment: surely if you expected people to spend time answering your questions, you can dedicate a bit of time to trying out the suggestions

Comment: One more thing: while it is better to use index (which I think we will in the future), is there any drawback of using the way mentioned except readability to future developer? It would take some time to rewrite previous code, so I need to see if I should immediately do the rewrite or suggest to put that on the next update.

Comment: Your approach will be more readable to an experienced developer than the current approach. You can make the database change without breaking old code by making use of mysql VIEWs